# I want to draw data from the web with Excel macro

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to take old programs from http://arsiv.sahadan.com/genis_ekran_iddaa_programi/. For this I modified the macro with the module called @QHarr, but I couldn't handle the tables. Macro doesn't work.

```
    Public Sub Deneme()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("X").Select
    Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim url As String, ws As Worksheet, html As HTMLDocument, http As clsHTTP, hTable As HTMLTable
    Dim headerRow As Boolean, trow As Object, tRows As Object, tCell As Object, tCells As Object
    Dim iRow As Long, R As Long, C As Long, Hsay As Long, numberOfRequests As Long
    Dim hafta(), results(), headers()
    headers = Array("Hsay", "Saat", "Lig", "Kod", "MBS", "Ev Sahibi", "Misafir", "IY", "MS", "MS1", "MSX", "MS2", "IY1", "IYX", "IY2", "he", "H1", "HX", "H2", "hm", "KGV", "GVY", "CS1/X", "CS1/2", "X/2", "IY1,5A", "IY1,5U", "1,5A", "1,5U", "2,5A", "2,5U", "3,5A", "3,5U", "TG01", "TG23", "TG46", "7+")
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    hafta = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Y").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("Y").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Value)
    Const numTableRows As Long = 500
    Const numTableColumns As Long = 37
    Const BASE_URL As String = "http://arsiv.sahadan.com/LargeProgram.aspx?"
    numberOfRequests = UBound(hafta)
    ReDim results(1 To numTableRows * numberOfRequests, 1 To numTableColumns)
    For Hsay = 1 To numberOfRequests
        headerRow = True
        url = BASE_URL & "id=weekId&value=" & hafta(Hsay)
        html.body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)
        Set hTable = html.querySelector("dvLargeHead")
        Set tRows = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each trow In tRows
            If Not headerRow Then
                C = 2: R = R + 1
                results(R, 1) = hafta(Hsay)
                Set tCells = trow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                For Each tCell In tCells
                    results(R, C) = tCell.innerText
                    C = C + 1
                Next
            End If
            headerRow = False
        Next
    Next
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "doesn't work"? Error message, for example?

Comment: gives error 91 in line.

Comment: Set tRows = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")

Comment: Can you give an example of one full URL created by  url = BASE_URL & "id=weekId&value=" & hafta(Hsay)   .... does it produce valid URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot successfully reproduce the ajax requests that are used to update the page. I get Access Denied which makes me think there must be some protocol/authentication I am missing beyond the simple query string part.

Below is an example using selenium basic. It is slow as I am copying all the formatting across as the layout is a little finicky.

I have written something without using the clipboard which I may add later if I am happy with. It is a lot faster.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, clipboard As Object
    Dim ele As Object, ws As Worksheet, t As Date, weeks As Object, i As Long
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 15
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "http://arsiv.sahadan.com/genis_ekran_iddaa_programi/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL, timeout:=90000

        Set weeks = .FindElementsByCss("#weekId option")
        .FindElementByCss("[value='-1']").Click
        For i = 1 To weeks.Count
            If i > 1 Then
                .FindElementsByCss("#weekId option")(i).Click
            End If
            Dim html As HTMLDocument
            Set html = New HTMLDocument
            t = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .FindElementByCss("#dvLarge #resultsList")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing

            If Not ele Is Nothing Then
                clipboard.SetText ele.Attribute("outerHTML")
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ws.Cells.UnMerge
                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
                ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
            End If

            Set ele = Nothing
        Next
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Dear Mr. @QHarr, thank you very much for your effort. However, the macro returns a "User-defined type not defined" error in the WebDriver object. Is there a reference to open?

Comment: This is selenium basic which requires installation of [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) and VBE >  tools > references > _selenium type library_ . I may write something for IE over next few days.

Comment: Do you have a value for BASE_URL & "id=weekId&value=" & hafta(Hsay) that works when pasted in the browser?

Comment: I don't know if the base url is correct. Hsay sample values ​​for base url; 18084
18085
18086
18087
18088
18089
18090
18091

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    var noww = new Date();
    var day = "0" + noww.getDate();
    var month = "0" + (noww.getMonth()+1);
    Mackolik.Program.sport = 1;
    Mackolik.Program.type = Mackolik.Program.sport == 1 ? 6 : 1;
    Mackolik.Program.sort = "-1";
    Mackolik.Program.sortDir = "-1";
    Mackolik.Program.sortValue = "DATE";
    Mackolik.Program.groupId = "-1";

Comment: Mackolik.Program.day = day.substr(day.length - 2, 2) + "." + month.substr(month.length - 2, 2) + "." + noww.getFullYear();
    Mackolik.Program.currentWeek = "18091";
    Mackolik.Program.week = "18091";
    Mackolik.Program.notPlayed = "1";
    Mackolik.Program.Large.getProgram();

Comment: Dear @QHarr I get a run-time error 33 error in the ".Start" Chrome "" line of code. What is the reason?

Comment: Likely you you either aren't using the latest chrome browser/chromedriver or chromedriver is not in the same folder as your selenium install. If you open the folder location of your selenium install and place your chromedriver.exe in there.

Comment: I did what you said and the code worked fine. Thanks.